# Ajax загрузка из бд

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку с помощю ajax из бд , но в ответ ничего не приходит , ошибок нету!

```js
(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/php/load.php',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (dataArr) {
                console.log(dataArr);
            }
        });
    })();
```

PHP Файл load

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

 $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','mysql','mysql','carbase');

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo 'Ошибка подключения к базе ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'): ' 
 .mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
 }
  $sql = "SELECT 
  id,mark,model,mile,price,describeru,describeen,describesv,img1 FROM 
 `cars` LIMIT 9";
 $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$res = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $res[] = $row;
 }

 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($res);
exit;
}
?>
```

error_log.php показывает 0 ошибок!В консоли также 0 ошибок!Версия php 5.6 возможно стоит повисить или понизить?

Если вписать echo json_encode($res); прямо в while то все работает и выводиться!

Comment: jQuery подключен? Ошибки в броузере/консоль разработчика смотрели?

Comment: jquery работает норм,в консоли пытаюсь вывести console.log(dataArr); но там просто пусто!

Comment: @JuniorCoder запустите `/php/load.php` напрямую, проверьте подключение, запрос, `$row`. Это первые действия прежде чем бежать к кому-то за советом.

Comment: Если сделать вывод  $row , то приходит 1 запись!

Comment: Можно код load.php ? Или он в том же файле что и jquery? Может я не прав - но скрипт к которому делаешь ajax должен что-то возвращать, например return json_encode(array('result' =>$result)); Смотри в консоле разработчика куда уходит твой запрос и что пишет сервер)

Comment: пример load.php есть выше

Comment: Ответ от сервера : status: 200​
statusText: "OK"

Comment: @JuniourCoder, я взял ваш чанк кода и оформил его в работающий скрипт, обернув его html-разметкой, корректным подключением jQuery и небольшими правками в php-коде: 1)в части возвращаемого скриптом Content-type; 2) url для ajax-запроса; 3) разделил его работу для двух контекстов - для POST и GET запросов.  Я его проверил - **у меня он работает**. Вы посмотрите мой ответ, он должен подсказать вам правильно решение. Или выложите свои скрипты, оформленные подобным способом, тогда вы быстрее получите помощь.

Comment: как правильно прописать url: '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>', с учетом url: '/php/load.php',

Comment: @JuniorCoder, так и указывайте ```url: '/php/load.php',```

Comment: Нечего не изменилось , сейчас заллю свой скрипт на основе вашего!

Comment: error_log.php показывает 0 ошибок!

Comment: @JuniourCoder,  в броузере, в консоли разработчика(закладка Сеть) какой Content-type в ответе ajax-запроса?

Comment: Content-Type 
application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: @JuniourCoder Content-Length больше 0?

Comment: Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Length 
0
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Tue, 05 Mar 2019 16:06:58 GMT
Server 
nginx/1.12.2
Upgrade 
h2,h2c
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.6.40

Comment: @JuniorCoder, но Content-Type не application/json, как вы комментировали выше! Если вы верно обновили в описании код скрипта upload.php, то значит у вас метод запроса к скрипту не POST. добавьте в скрипт, до оператора if строчку ```echo "foo" ; exit;``` И снова посмотрите вывод и заголовки ответа

Comment: Я тестил разные варианты скрипта, вот че выдает на скрипте что указан выше Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Length 
0
Content-Type 
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Tue, 05 Mar 2019 16:37:47 GMT
Server 
nginx/1.12.2
Upgrade 
h2,h2c
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.6.40

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90626/discussion-between-jigius-and-juniorcoder).

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий скрипт (данные для результата только не из БД):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
  /*$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','mysql','mysql','carbase');

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Ошибка подключения к базе ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'): ' .mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
  }
  $sql = "SELECT id,mark,model,mile,price,describeru,describeen,describesv,img1 FROM cars LIMIT 9";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

  $res = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res[] = $row;
  }*/

  $res[] = ['nissan', 'almera'];
  $res[] = ['toyota', 'corolla'];
  $res[] = ['vaz', 'taz'];
  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  echo json_encode($res);
  exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (dataArr) {
                console.log(dataArr);
            }
        });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Переписал под ваш скрипт, но не работает!